# JavaScript Get Time Central Time Zone

Tags: javascript

I am using a button to update a form field with a date and timestamp.  The issue now is that the request has been made so that anytime these are used they are being updated to the central time zone.  Can anyone help me update the below so I can accomodate?

```
function getTimeStamp() {
  var now = new Date();
  return ((now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (now.getDate()) + '/' + now.getFullYear() + " " + now.getHours() + ':' +
    ((now.getMinutes() < 10) ? ("0" + now.getMinutes()) : (now.getMinutes())) + ':' + ((now.getSeconds() < 10) ? ("0" + now
      .getSeconds()) : (now.getSeconds())));
}

function setTime() {
  document.getElementById('InsertRecordDate_Received').value = getTimeStamp();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/6016329

```
/** 
 * function to calculate local time
 * in a different city
 * given the city's UTC offset
 */
function calcTime(city, offset) {

    // create Date object for current location
    var d = new Date();

    // convert to msec
    // add local time zone offset
    // get UTC time in msec
    var utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

    // create new Date object for different city
    // using supplied offset
    var nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));

    // return time as a string
    return "The local time in " + city + " is " + nd.toLocaleString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what i needed

Comment: So for short, this code gets the time in Central Time Zone:
 `new Date(new Date().getTime() + (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000) + (3600000 * -6))`

Answer (score 4):

Check out `moment.js`, and its complement `moment-timezone.js`:

http://momentjs.com

http://momentjs.com/timezone

For example, this will output the current time converted to central timezone:

```
moment().tz('America/Chicago').format('hh:mm:ss z')
> 03:48:34 CST

moment().tz('America/Chicago').format('hh:mm:ss z Z')
> 03:50:35 CST -06:00

moment().tz('America/Chicago').format()
> 2016-12-05T15:52:09-06:00
```