# Shopify: make elmeont only appear during set time frame

Tags: javascript, css, shopify

I run the debut theme on Shopify. We offer local delivery and I'd like to do something like this: and have it only appear during our delivery hours. Would this need to be done in JavaScript?

EDIT: Sorry I didn’t realize it stopped my link. I’m wanting to do text in CSS similar to this: https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-neon-text-with-css/

I can handle the CSS. Was just curious if JavaScript is the best way to go about this.

I did find this and am going to try to adapt to my needs:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
  var d = new Date();
  if (d.getHours() > 12 && d.getHours() < 15) { // if it's after 1pm but before 3pm
    $('div').show();
  } else {
    $('div').hide();
  }
}, 1000 * 60) // this will run every minute
```

Comment: Yes, you can do that with Javascript. If you tell me in more detail, I can help you to do so. Let`s have a talk.

Comment: I appreciate the fast reply and truly appreciate the help. We offer delivery from 2pm-7pm CST. The goal is to just show this bit of CSS during those hours and have it hidden otherwise.

Comment: You can use moment.js library to calculate the certain time at CST Timezone. Then check if time is between 2pm-7pm so to hide or show your bit of CSS.

Comment: This [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40983650/javascript-get-time-central-time-zone has some useful info.